# Alternative implementation of INSTANCEOF when there are 'many' subclasses'

Tags: java, instanceof

I've tried looking for a proper solution, but had difficulties finding it.

This is quite a simple question - is there a proper, effective alternative of using INSTACEOF, when we want to determine a class type when there are **a lot** of that class's instancess?

**For example:**

We have a parent `Product` class

```
    public abstract class Product {

    public abstract String preview();

}
```

**Which has 3 subclasses (Vinyl, Book and Video)**

```
public class Vinyl extends Product {

@Override
public String preview() {
    return "Playing a vinyl";
}
```

}

```
public class Book extends Product {

@Override
public String preview() {
    return "Reading a book";
}
```

}

```
@Override
public String preview() {
    return "Playing a video";
}
```

Now, I want to check according for each product type it's preview method returned value - When we have **3** subclasses, it's quite clear and neat when writing:

```
    public class TestProduct {

    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void preview(Product product) {
        for (Product currentProduct : productList) {
            String preview = currentProduct.preview();

            if (product instanceof Book) {
                Assert.assertEquals(preview, "Reading a book");

            }   else if (product instanceof Vinyl) {
                Assert.assertEquals(preview, "Playing vinyl");

            } else {
                Assert.assertEquals(preview, "Playing video");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But what if we don't have 3 product, **but 100 or more?**
It's doesn't make me any sense writing a 100 times this `INSTACEOF` statements..
Is there any proper, scalable way?

Comment: or extend all classes from `product interface` and make a `generic list of anything that extends products` and iterate it using `for` loop for every `product you have`

Comment: But when interating the genereic list. how exactly should I determine the current item type?

Comment: Are you allowed to use an `interface` instead of an `abstract` class?

Comment: Sure - any implementation we wish. Is interface is preferable over an abstract class?

Comment: You shouldn't need it at all, let alone a 'better version'. Just use method override polymorphism as the gods of OO intended.

Comment: If you can't make the 'do something' a method of the classes you may use the visitor pattern (search for it).

Comment: @Henry: It might be a better solution, but you still need to be able to make the `accept(Visitor)` a method of all `Product` subclasses.

Comment: I added one possible answer if you have any doubts let me know

Comment: I have edited my question - what would you do different if you wanted to assert the returned value of a specific subclass?

Answer (score 3):

This is a possible implementation using `interface`:

```
public interface class Product {
    public void doSomething();
}
```

Then each subclass will have to implement its own doSomething()

```
public class Vinyl implements Product {
    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("Vinyl product");
    }
}

public class Book implements Product {
    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("Book product");
    }
}

public class Video implements Product {
    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("Video product");
    }
}
```

Then

```
Product product = new Vinyl();
product.doSomething();
// prints on the console --> "Vinyl product"
```

Same goes for the other classes that implements the interface product.
Abstract classes cannot be instantiated which in your case is of no help that's why I used interface.
Side note: generally when you need to use `instanceof`, then you are probably using the wrong design.

Comment: A very important side note.

Answer (score 2):

Why not make the work you're doing part of the subclass itself?

```
public abstract class Product {
    abstract void doSomething();
}
```

Then the code doing the looping doesn't need to know what type of product it has. It can let the product decide what to do.

```
for (Product product : products) {
    product.doSomething();
}
```

The `doSomething()` method can have arguments and a return type if you need.

You can also use the Visitor pattern for a variation on the same theme that lets you specify the implementation outside of the actual `Product` implementation class.

Comment: this is good approach when I need to acitivate current subclass method - but (I have edited my question) what will you do when you need to assert each subclass's specific returned value?

Comment: @Nimrod If one class is asserting something about the behaviour of another then your class design is broken.

Comment: @Nimrod is this a unit test? In that case, each `Product` subclass should be tested individually.

Comment: The scenario is to write a method which checks the items preview (like amazon preview results page). For each item (product) you need to check it's preview content. So if the current one is a vinyl product, you would expect the vinyl preview string

Answer (score 1):

It's not always practical or possible to use polymorphism or the Visitor pattern, e.g. when you can't change a subclass, or when there are many different situations where you want to `doSomething()` based on a specific subtype, e.g. when you have many different decorators — there you don't want that logic in subclasses themselves. In such situations you can use an external handler, like:

```
class Handler<T> {
    private Map<Class<? extends T>, Consumer<? super T>> handlers = new HashMap<>();

    Handler<T> register(Class<? extends T> subtype, Consumer<? super T> action) {
        handlers.put(subtype, action);
        return this;
    }

    void handle(T instance) {
        Optional.ofNullable(instance)
                .map(Object::getClass)
                .map(this.handlers::get)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Unknown subtype!"))
                .accept(instance);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Handler<Product> productHandler = new Handler<Product>()
        .register(Vinil.class, vinil -> gramophone.play(vinil.sideB()))
        .register(Book.class, book -> library.put(book.isbn(), book))
        .register(Video.class, video -> { /* no-op */ });

products.stream()
        .forEach(productHandler::handle);
```

Comment: While something along these lines would work, it's a perversion of polymorphism. I can't imagine it making life easier in the long term.

Answer (score 1):

one possible solution is to enjoy the polymorphism

```
public static void check(Object o) {
        List<? extends Products> list = Arrays.asList(new A(), new B(), new C());

            if (o instanceof Products) {
                Products p = (Products) o;
                p.doSomething();
            }
        }
```

and the interface is

```
public interface Products {
    public void doSomething();
}
```